# Will Logitech K380 and MX Master work on elementary OS?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I tried googling, but cannot find a definitive answer.

Here's the thing - I'm allergic to cables, so I'm using bluetooth everything. So far only Ubuntu allowed me to connect MX Master mouse and K380 keyboard at once (keyboard has this authentication thing where you have to type in the password shown on screen), but I really don't like this distro.

So here's the question: will I be able to use my keyboard and mouse with elementaryOS without having to spend hours in terminal installing plugins? I really love how reliable and fast Linuxes are, but lack of features like bluetooth support is a big pain. Hope that elementary will solve my issues.

Thanks in advance for all the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu is the base for Elementary OS anything that works in Ubuntu should work in it's derivatives.  If the mouse and keyboard worked in Ubuntu 16.04 it should work in Elementary Loki

Answer (score 0):

I have that mouse and it works just fine. The secondary buttons are mapped to back and forward and that works system wide. Can't say anything for the keyboard though.

Answer (score 0):

I've wireless keyboard (and mouse) both logitech. Keyboard K750 and MX mouse. They work like they should :)
There's also an indicator that show batteries on them.
[image]